# How to separate an <li> element (menu) in a vertical navigation-bar

Tags: html, css

Basically if you make a vertical navigation-bar, it becomes:

```
Item1
Item2
Item3
```

But I want it so that Item1 and Item2 on top, but Item3 on bottom, so it would look like

```
-- Top Screen --
Item1
Item2
.. empty ..
Item3
-- Bottom Screen --
```

Is there a way to do this? I've seen examples like making another div element on Item3 and make it float, but that would make the Item3 overlap the Item1 and Item2 if the screen becomes too short.

I've read some stuff in bootstrap and it has a function called navbar-right and navbar-left, so I assume this is possible.

Comment: can you provide any html and css you made till now?

Comment: add a span with `display:block;` between 2nd and 3rd `li` and give `height: 20px;` or whatever px's.

Comment: Separate the items with 2 divs, you can position both divs how you'd like. Please provide some html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your list relative.
The first two list-items can be placed without any special styling.

The last list item will be placed absolute, and giving a `bottom: 0` so it sticks to its parents bottom:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}
ul>li {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
ul>li:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an child seletors like this (if you want to select a specific li)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
li:nth-child(3) {
    margin-top:20px;
    background: #ff0000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
<li>The first paragraph.</li>
<li>The second paragraph.</li>
<li>The third paragraph.</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

or if you want to select the last one:

```
li:last-child {
    margin-top:20px;
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

Comment: Provide an example please.

Comment: I revised my answer ;)

Comment: Could you maby send what you have now. Just that i know what you want... You want the last item in the menu to have some space no matter hoe many items you have?

Comment: Thanks i adjusted my answer, hope it's oke like this

Answer (score 0):

You can add an id to item 3 CSS, and change it`s margin:

Your HTML

```
   <ul>
        <li>item1</li>
        <li>item2</li>
        <li id="item3">item3</li>
   </ul>
```

Your CSS

```
#item3{margin-top:20px;}
```

Comment: This could be achieved by :last-child or :nth-child(3)